# VBA Kerberos Authentication

Tags: vba, authentication, post, kerberos, winhttprequest

I want to send a POST request to a Java servlet with VBA using the Kerberos ticket from the Windows Log In for authentication and then retrieve a JSON response from the servlet. Can I achieve this without using an InternetExplorer object, e.g. using WinHttpRequest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WinHttpRequest` is not an IE object. The above described usecase works perfectly as long as you set up to relax the security permissions. I have implemented a proof of concept last year: Excel, VBA, REST, Tomcat, SPNEGO authentication.

Stub code:

```
Dim winHttp As Object
Set winHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

winHttp.SetAutoLogonPolicy (0)
winHttp.Open "GET", "http://..."
winHttp.send

Dim success As Boolean
success = winHttp.waitForResponse(5)
If Not success Then
    Debug.Print "DOWNLOAD FAILED!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim responseText As String
responseText = winHttp.responseText
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can the relaxing of the security permissions be done in VBA? Can you please post some of the relevant VBA code from your proof of concept?

Comment: Thanks again! I won't have the opportunity to test your code until Monday, I'll let you know whether it works by then.

Comment: @user1829001, I'd be glad to hear your results.

Comment: It appears the code doesn't work in my case. I get a response from the server which says "Your browser does not support SPNEGO/Kerberos authentication. Alternative authentication required.".

Comment: @user1829001, that should not be the case. You can and must do the following, inspect the traffic with Fiddler and Wireshark and see wether the framework does send a ticket at all. That code works here very good. Does it work with another client? I wouldn't share not working code.

Comment: It works when I use IE respectively the InternetExplorer.Navigate() function in VBA. I'll check the traffic as you suggested.

Comment: Fiddler tells me that IE sends a Cookie/Login to the server consisting of items "CTSESSION", "ssoLang", "TCSESSIONID" and "wt_eid". I guess I need to first retrieve this data in VBA and then send it as a cookie as well. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: @user1829001, that is not what I wanted to know. At first request from VBA, the server has to challange the client with `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate`. Please recheck.

Comment: I got the solution: actually it works exactly like in your code, the only missing was winHttp.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"

Comment: Has anyone managed to get this to work with Kerberos? I can't see how to get the Kerberos ticket using the example code mentioned above?

Comment: @jcwhall There is nothing to do. The underlying C/C++ code will do for you by default.